# Dynamically comparing these two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I compare these two php arrays against maximum similar values and get the key index from array_2 for which it has maximum matches from array_1? I can not do this using conventional if else condition as there are multiple conditions involves, is there any quick and robust way to do this?

```
$array_1 = array(
    'key_1'=> 'value_1',
    'key_2'=> 'value_2',
    'key_3'=> 'value_3'
);

$array_2 = array(
    [1] => array(
        'key_1'=> 'value_1',
        'key_2'=> 'value_2',
        'key_3'=> 'value_3',
        'key_4'=> 'value_4',
        'key_5'=> 'value_5'
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'key_1'=> 'value_1',
        'key_2'=> 'value_2',
        'key_3'=> 'value_3',
        'key_4'=> 'value_4',
        'key_5'=> 'value_5'
    ),
    [3] => array(
        'key_1'=> 'value_1',
        'key_2'=> 'value_2',
        'key_3'=> 'value_3',
        'key_4'=> 'value_4',
        'key_5'=> 'value_5'
    )
);
```

**Update:**

These are the actual arrays I am working with, I want to get the URL from array_2 for the maximum matched values with array_1

```
Array_1:

Array
(
    [country] => IN
    [os] => WINDOWS
    [device] => DESKTOP
    [bit] => 64
    [browser] => CHROME
)

or 

Array
(
    [country] => IN
    [os] => WINDOWS
    [device] => DESKTOP
    [bit] => 64
    [browser] => FIREFOX
)

Array_2:

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => IN
            [browser] => NONE
            [os] => WINDOWS
            [device] => DESKTOP
            [bit] => 64
            [url] => url-1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country] => IN
            [browser] => FIREFOX
            [os] => WINDOWS
            [device] => DESKTOP
            [bit] => 64
            [url] => url-2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [country] => IN
            [browser] => CHROME
            [os] => MACOS
            [device] => NONE
            [bit] => NONE
            [url] => url-3
        )

)
```

**Update 2:**

```
    $user_data = array();
    $user_data['country'] = get_user_cc();
    $user_data['os'] = get_user_os();
    $user_data['device'] = get_user_device();
    $user_data['bit'] = get_user_osbit();
    $user_data['browser'] = get_user_browser();

    $saved_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirects', true);

    if (!empty($saved_data)) {
        foreach ($saved_data as $data) {
            $new_data = $data;
            unset($new_data['url']);

            if($new_data['browser'] === 'NONE') {
                $user_data['browser'] = 'NONE';
            }

            if($new_data['os'] === 'NONE') {
                $user_data['os'] = 'NONE';
            }

            if($new_data['country'] === 'NONE') {
                $user_data['country'] = 'NONE';
            }

            if($new_data['device'] === 'NONE') {
                $user_data['device'] = 'NONE';
            }

            if($new_data['bit'] === 'NONE') {
                $user_data['bit'] = 'NONE';
            }  
            
            $match_count = count(array_intersect_assoc($user_data, $new_data));

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($match_count);
            echo '</pre>';
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: All the elements in `$array_2` have the same values.

Comment: Use `count(array_intersect_assoc($x, $y))` to get the number of similar elements between two arrays. Then loop over `$array_2`, doing this with the current element and `$array_1`. If the count is higher than the current maximum, save the index.

Comment: @Barmar no $array_2 values could be anything, they are dynamically generated, I want to match it with the maximum values it matches with. I tried count(array_intersect_assoc($x, $y)) but it didn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Do you need to match the keys and values of the arrays, or just the values?

Comment: It would be better if you made the example more representative, with different values in each array. Then say which element should be selected as the result.

Comment: I want to match both key and value

Comment: Then I don't know why `array_intersect_assoc()` isn't working.

Comment: Show what you tried, and then we can help you get it working.

Comment: @Barmar  Please check my update in the question, I have added the actual response arrays.

Comment: I'm more interested in the code, not the arrays.

Comment: Its a part of a long function, sharing whole code will not be possible here, I will try to create a repo, and share. Basically, Array_1 values are dynamically generated as per user, and array_2 are from saved settings. I want to get the URL from array_2 for which it matches maximum values with array_1 values.

Comment: We don't need the whole code, just the part that does this comparison.

Comment: It should be 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: `$match_count = count(array_intersect_assoc($array1, $element_of_array2));`. Use a foreach loop that gets the maximum value of `$match_count`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried your suggestion, but it is not fully working, please check my update 2, I have added code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217925/discussion-between-deepak-singh-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change `$user_data` during the loop, because that will interfere with later iterations. Make a copy of `$user_data` and update that.

You need to check if `$match_count` is higher than the current maximum. If it is, update the maximum and save the current URL.

```
$max_match = -1;

foreach ($saved_data as $data) {
    $temp_data = $user_data;
    $save_url = $data['url'];
    unset($temp_data['url']);

    if($data['browser'] === 'NONE') {
        $temp_data['browser'] = 'NONE';
    }

    if($data['os'] === 'NONE') {
        $temp_data['os'] = 'NONE';
    }

    if($data['country'] === 'NONE') {
        $temp_data['country'] = 'NONE';
    }

    if($data['device'] === 'NONE') {
        $temp_data['device'] = 'NONE';
    }

    if($data['bit'] === 'NONE') {
        $temp_data['bit'] = 'NONE';
    }  
            
    $match_count = count(array_intersect_assoc($user_data, $temp_data));

    if ($match_count > $max_match) {
        $max_match = $match_count;
        $url = $save_url;
    }
            
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($url);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This line should be $match_count = count(array_intersect_assoc($user_data, $data)); Thank you for your help, it gave me initial idea to do the job.

Comment: I thought you wanted to compare after filling in the `NONE` fields, why else do that?

Comment: Yes, but here we have set $temp_data = $user_data;  so array_intersect_assoc($user_data, $temp_data) will compare the same array.

Comment: No, because of all the `if` statements that change `$temp_data`.

Comment: Yes, In my case it is required.

Comment: I know, that's why you have to compare with `$temp_data`, because it's updated by those.